# Is it possible to include common-tests in serverspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, serverspec

I'm using [serverspec](http://serverspec.org/) to carry out remote testing of servers.

I've a number of different tests, which all work fine:

```
`-- spec
    |-- builder.example.org.uk
       \ host_spec.rb
    |-- chat.example.org.uk
       \ host_spec.rb
    |-- docker.example.org.uk
       \ host_spec.rb
    \-- git.example.org.uk
       \ host_spec.rb
```

However each host-test has a lot of duplication, because I want to ensure that each host has `sshd` running, for example.

I've tried several different ways of creating `spec/common_tests.rb` but each time fails.  For example adding `spec/common.rb`:

```
 describe command("lsb_release -d") do
    its(:stdout) { should match /wheezy/ }
 end
```

Then in `spec/chat.example.org.uk/host_spec.rb`:

```
 require 'common'
```

However this seems to suddenly want to connect to a different host, and fail:

```
shelob ~ $ bundle exec rake spec:ssh.example.org.uk 
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -S rspec spec/ssh.example.org.uk/host_spec.rb
F.....................

Failures:

   1) Command "lsb_release -d" stdout
      On host `ssh.example.org.uk`
      Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
      SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

So my question is twofold:

- Is it possible to include common tests from an external file?
- If so how do I accomplish this?

Comment: What about symlinking specs into host directories?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work.

Comment: For the moment I've hacked up a solution using `cpp` to include files into the specs, and written a `Makefile` to do the necessary.  Not pleasant, but it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your example has a typo, as it seems to do exactly what you want. You're running `bundle exec rake spec:ssh.example.org.uk` and it's running against `ssh.example.org.uk`.

The [serverspec documentation](http://serverspec.org/advanced_tips.html) suggests another way to run shared specs. Instead of organising your files by *host*, you should organise them by *role*. For instance:

```
`-- spec
    |-- app
    |   `-- ruby_spec.rb
    |-- base
    |   `-- users_and_groups_spec.rb
    |-- db
    |   `-- mysql_spec.rb
    |-- proxy
    |   `-- nginx_spec.rb
    `-- spec_helper.rb
```

Then, in your `Rakefile`, you map your hosts to roles:

```
hosts = [{name: 'www.example.org.uk', roles: %w(base app)},
         {name: 'db.example.org.uk', roles: %w(base db)}]
```

You can then provide a `ServerSpecTask` that runs commands by setting the host address as an environment variable, by overriding [RSpec's `spec_command` method](http://apidock.com/rspec/1.1.4/Autotest/Rspec/spec_command):

```
class ServerspecTask < RSpec::Core::RakeTask
  attr_accessor :target

  def spec_command
    cmd = super
    "env TARGET_HOST=#{target} #{cmd}"
  end

end

namespace :serverspec do
  hosts.each do |host|
    desc "Run serverspec to #{host[:name]}"
    ServerspecTask.new(host[:name].to_sym) do |t|
      t.target = host[:name]
      t.pattern = 'spec/{' + host[:roles].join(',') + '}/*_spec.rb'
    end
  end
end
```

And then finally, update your `spec_helper.rb` to read that environment variable and use it as the host:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.host  = ENV['TARGET_HOST']
  options = Net::SSH::Config.for(c.host)
  user    = options[:user] || Etc.getlogin
  c.ssh   = Net::SSH.start(c.host, user, options)
  c.os    = backend.check_os
end
```

Comment: It does seem that way - but in short if you include/require a file inside a working host you get a spurious error about "Name or service not known".

Comment: Grouping by role doesn't really work for me in my current situation, but it seems like the closest _supported_ solution, so I guess even though it doesn't satisfy i should give you the bounty.

Comment: "Name or service not known" suggests that it's trying to ssh to a hostname that doesn't resolve via DNS (ie. the lookup for "foo.example.com" doesn't return an IP address). This probably indicates that you're in unsupported waters, as you suggest, but it's worth double-checking for typos too.

Comment: Another thing worth checking: what's the value of `RSpec.configuration.host` within your shared task?